# Why is $f_1^2=f_1f_2=1$?

Tags: calculus, induction, proof-explanation

In a proof by induction why $\sum_{i=0}^n f^2_i = f_nf_{n+1}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ the base case from the solution is $f_1^2=f_1f_2=1$. I assume $f$ denotes a function, but from the exercise there is no information given what $f$ denotes. So why is $f_1^2=f_1f_2=1$?

The exercise is the seventh from [this sheet](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/213/inductionsampler.pdf) if additional information is needed.

Comment: Are we not missing some crucial information? EDIT: It looks like fibonacci

Comment: $f_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: If you know the Fibonacci numbers then you will know that the first and the second number is 1. Therefore $f_1 = f_2 = 1$

Comment: If you read the solution, you will find that $f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_n$ is used in the Induction step. In addition, the solution assumes $f_2=1$, and perhaps $f_1=1$ is also hidden somewhere. All said and done, I think $f_n$ must have been defined in class to be the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number, so the teacher probably did not bother to define it again in the Problem sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of the inductive step mentions the recurrence relation defining the $f$-numbers - namely that $f_{k+2} = f_{k} + k_{k+1}$ and that gives it away: $f_n$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number.